# Python 3 - Weak reference error on cursor when using MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, weak-references

Having trouble understanding whats wrong with some pretty basic Python 3 code. Its a database class using MySQL connector which is then inherited in another class.

The database class (database.py):

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': '...',
    'password': '...',
    'database': '...'
}

class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
            self.cursor = db.cursor()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print(err.msg)
            return False
```

The class that inherits the database class:

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from database import Database

class Logger(Database):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_row(self, id):
        try:
            sql = ("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id = %s")
            self.cursor.execute(sql, (id,))
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            return result
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print(err.msg)
            return False
```

And the calling code ...

```
obj = Logger()
data = obj.get_row(2)
```

The weak reference error (on cursor):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples.py", line 71, in <module>
   data = obj.get_row(2)
 File "examples.py", line 28, in get_row
   self.cursor.execute(sql, (id,))
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

What am I not understanding here? I know the error is specific to the use of the MySQL connector as I have read that it uses weak references. I am just confused as to how I can reuse / maintain a reference to the **cursor** attribute of the parent class properly in my inherited class methods. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently the cursor holds no reference to the connection it is on, so after connect() the connection is Garbage collected. Hold a reference to it.

Comment: I understand that ... the question is how?

Comment: Instead of db = mysql.... use self.db = mysql.... That makes a reference to the connection* from your instance so it will not be collected, just like your cursor*.

Comment: * it is not your cursor that is garbage, but the connection.

Comment: Many thanks @MennoHölscher ! overlooked the self on db ;)